# What to do with the [diesease] tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

I noticed there is a [diesease](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diesease) tag on 3 questions:

- [What happened? - Chilli plants are developing spots on leaves and the edges are curling](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/14879/what-happened-chilli-plants-are-developing-spots-on-leaves-and-the-edges-are)
- [Why is my philodendron getting these brown dry parts on its leaves?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/14949/why-is-my-philodendron-getting-these-brown-dry-parts-on-its-leaves)
- [What is causing my Dracaena deremensis to develop brown spots and die?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/30384/what-is-causing-my-dracaena-deremensis-to-develop-brown-spots-and-die)

. Since it's a typo, should this tag be deleted? Or should it simply be merged with the [diseases](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diseases) tag?

Comment: I jumped the gun and retagged them all.

Comment: But Diesease is a thing: https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/44/49/84/44498410e1e59c25174b2ccf1a0c0f29.jpg

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think it should be deleted and the 3 questions edited with the correct tag.

Comment: Absolutely! There's no point in keeping a misspelled tag around.

Comment: good answer and good point; also, to leave misspelled tags (cf alternative spelling tags), could be misleading to readers & contributors